# 500: Internal Server Error. Tornado Upload App

Tags: python, web-services, upload, tornado, image-uploading

I was in the need of letting users upload pictures from a PhoneGap application using Tornado on my server, so I used a piece of code found on another question:
[How to upload an image with python-tornado from an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909397/how-to-upload-an-image-with-python-tornado-from-an-html-form)

The code as seen there works perfectly fine. But sadly what I'm sending to the server isn't exactly a file, but a base64 encoded string. So I up a "test lab" on UNIX machine did some modifications on the code, so I would receive the string and another agrgument I needed to use to name the file after decoding the string. When I launch the service it starts normally, but when I try to access it from the browser, it instantly show 500: Internal Server Error. The only part of the code I modified was the UploadHandler, everything else is exactly the same. I'm pretty new to python so I know probably I did something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import tornado.httpserver, tornado.ioloop, tornado.web, os.path, random, string
from tornado.options import (define, options)

define("port", default=8884, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", IndexHandler),
            (r"/upload", UploadHandler)
        ]
        settings = {
            'template_path': 'templates',
            'static_path': 'static',
            'xsrf_cookies': False
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("subir-string.html")


class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        b64string = self.get_argument("imageData","")
        v_id = self.get_argument("id","")

    if b64string:
        try:

            new_name = "uploads/%s.jpg" % v_id
            c = 0
            while  os.path.isfile(new_name):
                base, ext = os.path.splitext(new_name)
                new_name =  "uploads/%s-%s%s" % (base, c, ext)
                c= c + 1                    
            output_file = open(new_name, 'w')
            output_file.write(base64.decodestring(b64string))
        except Exception as e:
            print "Error: %s"%(e)
            self.finish(" Can't process request")
        else:
            self.finish(" File Uploaded " + new_name)

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = Application()
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug mode on the Tornado application? http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/overview.html#debug-mode-and-automatic-reloading

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had not tried that. Honestly I didn't know it was possible. That solved my problem.