# Tornado: Read uploaded CSV file?

Tags: python, file-upload, csv, tornado

I want to do something like:

```
import csv
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        uploaded_csv_file = self.request.files['file'][0]
        with uploaded_csv_file as csv_file:
            for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
                self.write(' , '.join(row))
```

But, `uploaded_csv_file` is not of type `file`.

What is the best practice here?

Sources:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911972/242933

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader) explains:

> `csvfile` can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `next()` method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable.

So, if you have something which is not a file, but is an iterator over lines, that's fine. If it's not even an iterator over lines, just wrap it in one. For a trivial example, if it's something with a `read_all()` method, you can always do this:

```
uploaded_csv_file = self.request.files['file'][0]
contents = uploaded_csv_file.read_all()
lines = contents.splitlines()
for row in csv.reader(lines):
    # ...
```

(Obviously you can merge steps together to make it briefer; I just wrote each step as a separate line to make it simpler to understand.)

Of course if the CSV files are large, and especially if they take a while to arrive and you've got a nice streaming interface, you probably don't want to read the whole thing at once this way. Most network server frameworks offer nice protocol adapters to, e.g., take a stream of bytes and give you a stream of lines. (For that matter, even `socket.makefile()` in the stdlib sort of does that…) But in your case, I don't think that's an issue.