# Python - open uploaded file

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Tornado web application where I want to read the an uploaded file. This is received from the client and I try to do so like this:

```
def post(self):

    file = self.request.files['images'][0]

    dataOpen = open(file['filename'],'r');
    dataRead = dataOpen.read()
```

But it gives an `IOError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rsaxdsxc\workspace\pi\src\Server.py", line 4100, in post
    dataOpen = open(file['filename'],'r');
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'000c02c55024aeaa96e6c79bfa2de3926dbd3767.jpg'
```

Why isn't it able to see the file?

Comment: Is the file located in your working directory?

Comment: It's a file uploaded from the web client

Comment: Well, you need to ensure that the directory matches where Python is trying to grab it from. Else you can use an absolute path.

Comment: Ensure that you write your file on upload before read it. With write(file['body'])

Answer (score 1):

Value of `file['filename']` is just name of uploaded file, it is not path in your filesystem. Content of file is in `file['body']`. You can use StringIO module to emulate file interface if you want, or just directly iterate over `file['body']`.

Very good example you could use is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909397/how-to-upload-an-image-with-python-tornado-from-an-html-form)

So, your post request handler could look like:

```
def post(self):

    file = self.request.files['images'][0]
    dataRead = file['body']
    store_file_somewhere(file['filename'], dataRead)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if this an uploaded image that is going to be stored directly into a database then how would you create a path on a remote server to then save the file into the database?

Comment: are you going to store path to image file in db or all the binary content of image file?

Comment: I want to store straight into the DB and was able to do so with `GridFS` for mongoDB. Thanks