# How to get Text from b'Text' in the pandas object type after using read_sas?

Tags: python, object, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read the data from .sas7bdat format of SAS using pandas function read_sas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sas('D:/input/houses.sas7bdat', format = 'sas7bdat')
df.head()
```

And I have two data types in the df dataframe - float64 and object. I completely satisfied with the float64 datatype, so I can freely convert it to int, string etc. 
The problem is with object data type, which I can see in the df dataframe wrapped like this:

```
b'Text'
```

or like this:

```
b'12345'
```

instead of

```
Text
```

or

```
12345
```

I can't convert it to string or int respectively or to "normal" object data type. Also I can't eleminate b'' using slice or replace technics. So I'm not able to use columns with the object data type. 
Please, tell me how can I get rid of b''.

Comment: Here you have reference to similar problem in Python: [Convert bytes to a Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

add this `encoding="utf-8"`

so the line would be as follows:

```
df = pd.read_sas('D:/input/houses.sas7bdat', format = 'sas7bdat', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: encoding can be `encoding="ISO-8859-1" `

Comment: This gives me an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Answer (score 23):

First, figure out your sas dataset encoding.
In SAS, run proc contents on the dataset.  Check the "Encoding".  In my case, my encoding was "latin1 Western (ISO)".  Then enter your encoding as such:

```
df = pd.read_sas('filename', format = 'sas7bdat', encoding = 'latin-1')
```

Comment: Perfect this worked just fine .. removed b' ' from whole dataframe. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `encoding` argument in `pd.read_sas()` leads me to have very large dataframes which lead me to have memory related errors.

An other way to deal with the problem would be to `convert` the byte strings to an other encoding (e.g. `utf8`).

#### Example:

Example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], 
                   "B": [b"a", b"b", b"c"], 
                   "C": ["a", "b", "c"]})
```

Transform byte strings to strings:

```py
for col in df:
    if isinstance(df[col][0], bytes):
        print(col, "will be transformed from bytestring to string")
        df[col] = df[col].str.decode("utf8")  # or any other encoding
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  a  a
1  2  b  b
2  3  c  c
```

Useful links:

1. [Pandas Series.str.decode() page of GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-decode/) (where I found my solution)
2. [What is the difference between a string and a byte string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)