# I am new in python. I have SAS data imported using pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am new in python. I have SAS data imported using pandas. The data is coming in below format.

```
CLASCODE    CLASDESC 
b'CT'       b'CTS-item' 
b'RI'       b'Request for information'
```

I want to remove `b` and `''` from the data through pandas or numpy. Please help.

Comment: These are just the representation of raw byte strings, there is no "b" character in those strings.

Comment: [`pandas.read_sas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sas.html) might be what you're looking for. A related post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930583/how-to-get-text-from-btext-in-the-pandas-object-type-after-using-read-sas.

Comment: thanks Bill, It is working fine now using encoding="utf-8"

Comment: Bill, I have another file to load. I did the same process but it is giving me below error.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: invalid start byte

i used this command to read the file

d=pd.read_sas('nameaddr.sas7bdat',encoding="utf-8")

Answer (score 0):

Look for proper encoding while you do parsing. However, if you have to go with current way then here's how you can remove `'` and `b`.

```
# Assuming data stored in series
s = pd.Series("CLASCODE CLASDESC b'CT' b'CTS-item' b'RI' b'Request for information'")
s = s.str.replace("'","")
s = s.str.replace("b","")
# CLASCODE CLASDESC CT CTS-item RI Request for information
```

Comment: Thanks meW, I am having facing another issue below is error message.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0

command i am using to read the sas data is below

d=pd.read_sas('nameaddr.sas7bdat',encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Please suggest here

Comment: Add a new question for that