# ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long PyCrypto 2.7a1

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm making programm for my school project and have one problem above.
Here's my code:

```
def aes():
    #aes
    os.system('cls')
    print('1. Encrypt')
    print('2. Decrypt')

    c = input('Your choice:')

    if int(c) == 1:
        #cipher
        os.system('cls')
        print("Let's encrypt, alright")
        print('Input a text to be encrypted')
        text = input()

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'w')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()

        BLOCK_SIZE = 32
        PADDING = '{'
        pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
        EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
        secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

        f = open('aeskey.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(secret))
        f.close()

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'r')
        privateInfo = f.read()
        f.close()

        cipher = AES.new(secret)

        encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, privateInfo)

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(encoded))
        f.close()
        print(str(encoded))

    if int(c) == 2:
        os.system('cls')
        print("Let's decrypt, alright")

        f = open('plaintext.txt','r')
        encryptedString = f.read()
        f.close()

        PADDING = '{'
        DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
        encryption = encryptedString

        f = open('aeskey.txt', 'r')
        key = f.read()
        f.close()

        cipher = AES.new(key)
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'w')
        f.write(decoded)
        f.close()

        print(decoded)
```

Full error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/vital/Desktop/Prog/Python/Enc_dec/Enc_dec.py", line 341, in aes() 
File "C:/Users/vital/Desktop/Prog/Python/Enc_dec/Enc_dec.py", line 180, in aes cipher = AES.new(key) 
File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 179, in new return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 114, in init blockalgo.BlockAlgo.init(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py", line 401, in init self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's 3.5, it's version of pycrypto 2.7a1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is very clear. The key must be exactly of that size. `os.urandom` will return you the correct key. However this key is a *bytes* (binary string value). Furthermore, by using `str(secret)`, the value of `repr(secret)` is written into the file instead of `secret`.

What is more confusing is that `AES.new` allows you to pass the key as Unicode! However, suppose the key was the ASCII bytes `1234123412341234`. Now,

```
f.write(str(secret))
```

will write `b'1234123412341234'` to the text file! Instead of 16 bytes, it now contains those 16 bytes + the `b`, and two `'` quote characters; 19 bytes in total.

Or if you take a random binary string from `os.urandom`,

```
>>> os.urandom(16)
b'\xd7\x82K^\x7fe[\x9e\x96\xcb9\xbf\xa0\xd9s\xcb'
```

now, instead of writing 16 bytes `D7`, `82`,.. and so forth, it now writes that string into the file. And the error occurs because the decryption tries to use

```
"b'\\xd7\\x82K^\\x7fe[\\x9e\\x96\\xcb9\\xbf\\xa0\\xd9s\\xcb'"
```

as the decryption key, which, when encoded as UTF-8 results in

```
b"b'\\xd7\\x82K^\\x7fe[\\x9e\\x96\\xcb9\\xbf\\xa0\\xd9s\\xcb'"
```

which is a 49-bytes long `bytes` value.

---

You have 2 good choices. Either you continue to write your key to a text file, but convert it to hex, or write the key into a binary file; then the file should be exactly the key length in bytes. I am going for the latter here:

Thus for storing the key, use

```
    with open('aeskey.bin', 'wb') as keyfile:
        keyfile.write(secret)
```

and

```
    with open('aeskey.bin', 'rb') as keyfile:
        key = keyfile.read()
```

---

Same naturally applies to the cipher text (that is the encrypted binary), you must write and read it to and from a binary file:

```
    with open('ciphertext.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(encoded)
```

and

```
    with open('ciphertext.bin', 'rb') as f:
        encryptedString = f.read()
```

If you want to base64-encode it, do note that `base64.b64encode/decode` are `bytes`-in/`bytes`-out.

By the way, [plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext) is the original, unencrypted text; the encrypted text is called [ciphertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext). AES is a cipher that can encrypt plaintext to ciphertext and decrypt ciphertext to plaintext using a key.

Despite these being called "-text" neither of them is textual data per se, as understood by Python, but they're binary data, and should be represented as `bytes`.

Comment: sorry, but now i have new error:

ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

Comment: in lines:
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

Comment: @ВиталикЛукьянов apply the same to your ciphertext! open the ciphertext file as binary, and write binary to it. It is not "plaintext" and should perhaps not written to a file named `plaintext.txt`.

Comment: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" in lines:
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)
    DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

Comment: How about `b'{'`. Please make sure that you [thoroughly understand the `bytes`/`str` distinction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string). It is the very foundation on which everything here builds.