# python bytes(some_string, 'UTF-8') and str(some_string, 'UTF-8')

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to adapt a code written for python3 to python2.7 while doing so I am getting errors because of the this two

> bytes(some_string, 'UTF-8') and str(some_string, 'UTF-8')

My Question:

Is following a correct way to adapt str(some_string, 'UTF-8')

> a = str(some_string)
>
> a = a.encode('UTF-8')

and how to adapt bytes(some_string, 'UTF-8') to python2.7 as bytes are introduced in python3.

Comment: in python 2 normal string is bytes, and `string.decode()` convert it into unicode. In python 3 normal string is unicode.

Comment: I cant't test it but `str(some_string, 'utf-8')` can be `some_string.decode('utf-8')` and `bytes(some_string, 'utf-8')` can be `some_string.encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 5):

Just `some_string` or `str(some_string)` will do in python2, since `some_string` is already an ascii string, and both of those actions convert it to type `str`.
In python 3 the str type is the same as the unicode type in python 2.

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string), I think it answers your questions nicely.

> In Python 2, str and bytes are the same type:
>
> bytes is str True In Python 3, the str type is Python 2's unicode type, which is the default encoding of all strings.

In other words, `bytes(some_string, 'UTF-8')` in python 2 is just `str(some_string)`, because `str` *is* a byte string.