# Extra Character: TensorFlow HelloWorld to Verify Correct Installation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

This is to make sure the result received from tensorFlow hello-world here is fine
[The hello-world page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

> If the Python program outputs the following, then the installation is successful and you can begin writing TensorFlow programs. (If you are new to TensorFlow, see Getting Started with TensorFlow.)
>
> `>Hello, TensorFlow!`

What happens actually is to receive the output:

```
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

In particular it has an extra ''b'' inside which is not expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b` is not a string character (it is not within the quotes) but a prefix, indicating that the string is a byte literal containing ASCII character (as opposed to the standard python3 utf-8 encoding).

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

Comment: If that is what we should expect, why it is not mentioned in tensorflow getting started tutorial, as the expected output?

Comment: They mention the result of `print(sess.run(hello))`, which should indeed be `Hello, TensorFlow!`. Yours looks rather like the output of `sess.run(hello)`.

Comment: No, it is still: b'Hello, TensorFlow!'

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would need an explicit decoding to print its content as a string. Things are working as described in python 2 though, where string conventions are different. My guess is that they prefer to keep the same code for both python versions even though the output might differ slightly, as presently.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It shows that this is a byte string (not a string). To know the difference, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string).

In short, a string can't be directly stored on a disk directly. It has to be encoded first & converted to byte string (a sequence of bytes). It can also be decoded back to a string.
So, here if you don't wish to see that extra 'b', you can use the decode() function.