# Validating Windows Installation of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

It states at:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

that the output should be:

Hello, TensorFlow!

but when I run the same 4 lines I get:

b'Hello, TensorFlow!'

noting the additional '' and letter b.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra Character: TensorFlow HelloWorld to Verify Correct Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508491/extra-character-tensorflow-helloworld-to-verify-correct-installation)

Answer (score 1):

The additional '' and letter b appear because it is a byte string (and not a unicode string). If you decode it by running

```
print(sess.run(hello).decode())
```

You will get

```
Hello, TensorFlow!
```