# Why aren't a result from "pack" equal to an array of bytes created manually?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this:

```
>>> a1 = pack('>L', 18)
>>> a1
b'\x00\x00\x00\x12'
```

And:

```
>>> a2 = [int(0x0), int(0x0), int(0x0), int(0x12)]
>>> a2
[0, 0, 0, 18]
```

Why aren't they equal?

```
>>> a1 == a2
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to transform the second variable `a2` in a [`byte string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string) if you want to be equals, `a1` is a **`list of ints`**, and `a2` is a **`byte string`**, so they will never be equeal unless you transform `a2`, for example:

```
import struct
import array

a1 = struct.pack('>L', 18)
print(a1)
$b'\x00\x00\x00\x12'

a2 = [int(0x0), int(0x0), int(0x0), int(0x12)]
print(a2)
$[0, 0, 0, 18] #this is a list

print(a1 == a2)
$False

a3 = array.array('B',a2).tostring() #transform the list into byte
print(a3)
$b'\x00\x00\x00\x12' 

print(a1 == a3)
$True
```

Comment: `#transform the list into byte` --> what's the byte here?

Comment: @Ko32mo b'\x00\x00\x00\x12' this is a byte string, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: @Ko32mo don't forget it is a good practice to accept (only one) answer (by click the check box in the left top of the answer) if the answer was helpul :), also don't forget to vote if you found the answer useful

Comment: @Ko32mo also check this link if you feel a little loss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string

Answer (score 0):

`pack('>L', 18)` returns a byte object and `a2` is a list.

Comment: what's a byte object?

Answer (score 0):

A list and a byte string aren't equivalent types, even though they're similar. To convert your list to a byte string, you can use the following methods depending on whether you're using Python 2 or 3.

Python 2:

```
>>> ''.join(chr(c) for c in a2)
'\x00\x00\x00\x12'
```

Python 3:

```
>>> bytes(a2)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x12'
```

Comment: what's a byte string? what's a real world example? does byte string exist in other programming languages?