# How to concatenate many binary file in one file in python?

Tags: python

I need to append many binary files  in one binary file. All my binary files are saved i one folder:

```
   file1.bin
   file2.bin
   ...
```

For that I try by using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
Power_Result_File_Path ="/home/Deep_Learning_Based_Attack/Test.bin"
Folder_path =r'/home/Deep_Learning_Based_Attack/Test_Folder/'  
os.chdir(Folder_path)
npfiles= glob.glob("*.bin")
loadedFiles = [np.load(bf) for bf in binfiles]
PowerArray=np.concatenate(loadedFiles, axis=0)
np.save(Power_Result_File_Path, PowerArray)
```

It gives me this error:

```
    "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
OSError: Failed to interpret file 'file.bin' as a pickle
```

My problem is how to  concatenate binary file it is not about anaylysing every file indenpendently.

Comment: @Bellian , In that case they loading a text file not a binary file, in my case It is absolutely that numpy library is not able to interpret a binary file for that I have that pickle error.

Comment: The answers given in the linked questions will not help to solve this question. Not a duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm good point.. is the `binfiles` a typo or where is it from? I only see definition of `npfiles`

Answer (score 0):

### Taking your question literally: Brute raw data concatenation

```
files = ['my_file1', 'my_file2']
out_data = b''
for fn in files:
  with open(fn, 'rb') as fp:
    out_data += fp.read()
with open('the_concatenation_of_all', 'wb') as fp:
  fp.write(out_data)
```

### Comment about your example

You seem to be interpreting the files as saved numpy arrays (i.e. saved via `np.save()`). The error, however, tells me that you didn't save those files via numpy (because it fails decoding them). Numpy uses `pickle` to save and load, so if you try to open a random non-pickle file with `np.load` the call will throw an error.

Comment: I have a binary file, file.bin

Comment: that makes no difference. When you open the file as 'rb' it reads it as a bytes string (which is also the type of `out_data`, note the `b`before the empty string. [**that `b`is very important**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string))

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in files:
  async with aiofiles.open(file, mode='rb') as f:
    contents = await f.read()
  if file == files[0]:
    write_mode = 'wb'  # overwrite file
  else:
    write_mode = 'ab'  # append to end of file

  async with aiofiles.open(output_file), write_mode) as f:
    await f.write(contents)
```