# Why the result prints b'hello,Python!' ,when I use tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

the code is pinned underneath:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello=tf.constant("hello,Python!")

sess=tf.Session()

print(sess.run(hello))
```

[image]

the current result is pinned underneath:

> b'hello,Python!'

then the screenshot

so,what shall I do to drop the strange "b" before the current result?

Comment: My description may be a little bit puzzling, actually, after I ran the code, the head of the result showed a "b" which confused me a lot.

Comment: The `b` character prefix signifies that `Hello, TensorFlow!` is a [byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Python 2.x [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the
>   literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is
>   automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be
>   followed by an 'r' prefix.

So in Python 3.x

> bytes = b'...' literals = a sequence of octets (integers between 0 and
>   255)

It's not really there, it only gets printed. This should not cause any problem anywhere.

You can try **decode("utf-8")** to convert it to str.

Works for me

```
>>> print(out)
b'hello,Python!'
>>> out.decode('utf-8')
'hello,Python!'
```

Comment: This is a temporary solution. So, need to change it every time. Is there any permanent solution for this?