# Python Socket Program

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to write a socket program using Python. In my client side I have this section:

```
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)         
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

linesInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(linesInBytes)
```

AND in my Server side I have:

```
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
#Set secret word
word = 'Arkansas'
linesForString = ''     
#Prints out number of letters
for x in word:
    linesForString += '_ '

linesInBytes = linesForString.encode('utf-8')
connectionSocket.send(linesInBytes)
```

And for some reason when it prints out on the client side, it prints out:

b'_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ '

And there is no where in the code where I print out a b. Where is this b coming from??
Thank you!

Comment: try printing linesInBytes before sending it and see what it contains, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: Also, do you really need the encoding?

Comment: In Python `b'....'` represents a byte string (that is, a string of raw bytes with no associated encoding). See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string).

Comment: @JLev bytes must be sent over the connection. Python 3 strings are Unicode so they must be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

`.decode('utf8')` the received data bytes back to a string. Python 3 displays `b''` to indicate a byte string vs. a Unicode string.