# what is the b in front of my results

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello  i have made a python script that tells me my usage of my disk on my nas over ssh but everytime i run the program i get this.

```
size b'442G' used b' 401M' available b'419G'
```

i want to get rid of the b and the quotes around the 422G and the others.

here is my code

```
import sys, paramiko
import os
import time



username = "alex"
hostname = "192.168.1.91"
password = "alex"
command = "df /dev/sda3 -h"
port = 22
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

def updateTimeMenu():
    time_menu.delete(0, "end")
    time_menu.add_command(label=time.ctime())


def ssh():
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
    menu()




def menu():
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.read()
    print("Size", output[65:69], ", Used", output[70:75], ", Available", output[77:81]) #should output hdd info (size, used, avalable)
    time.sleep(4)
    ssh()
ssh()
```

Comment: [Bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string

Comment: If that code is unedited, you may want to consider choosing a better password!

Comment: i know the password is not secure but it only gets access to 450gb partition on my NAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you retrieve a *binary* string, since a program can send all types of bytes through a channel, we can `decode` it to a string with `.decode('ascii')`:

```
print("Size",
      output[65:69].decode('ascii'),
      ", Used",
      output[70:75].decode('ascii'),
      ", Available",
      output[77:81].decode('ascii'))
```

Note that we here thus use the *ASCII "codec"*, since that seems the one used, but there are of course several ways to encode a string in raw bytes.

Comment: thank you this has helped me so much. i have been working on this code for hours trying to decode it