# "must be str, not bytes"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sockets

I wrote a server on python:

```
import  socket
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))

server_socket.listen(1)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()

client_name = client_socket.recv(1024)
client_socket.send('Hello ' + client_name)

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

And, I wrote a client:

```
import socket

my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))

my_socket.send('Sami')
data = my_socket.recv(1024)
print('The server sent: ' + data)

my_socket.close()
```

But when I run the codes, in the server I get the error: `"must be str, not bytes"` and in the client I get the error: `"a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"`.

Comment: You are mixing your `str` typing and your `bytes` typing. When you send data you should be sending `bytes` when you are printing it out they should be `str`

Comment: So how should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a string and a byte string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

Comment: Please tag your major Python version (2 or 3).

Comment: @AmitaiF if you are using python 3, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3 for methods to convert from bytes to string and viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

Use `encode/decode` to convert between `str` and `bytes` before sending and after receiving:

```
my_socket.send('Sami'.encode('utf-8'))  # encode string before sending
data = my_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')  # decode string after receiving
```

You can replace [`'utf-8'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) with other character encodings depending on your use case (you might see [`'cp1252'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) used in Windows applications, for instance).

For the server, rather than decoding the string and encoding it again after putting `'Hello '` on the front, you can skip a step and do this:

```
client_name = client_socket.recv(1024)
client_socket.send(b'Hello ' + client_name)
```

`b'Hello'` is a literal `bytes` object, rather than a `str` object like `'Hello'`. So `b'Hello' + client_name` will do `bytes + bytes = bytes` directly, rather than converting `client_name` to `str` with `.decode`, adding `'Hello'` to get another `str` and then converting back to `bytes` with `.encode`.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: @AmitaiF can you be more specific? what is the error?

Comment: At the server: client_socket.send('Hello ' + client_name) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'. At the client: print('The server sent: ' + data) TypeError: must be str, not bytes.

Comment: @AmitaiF Edited my answer, I didn't notice that you had another `send` in the server code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode before sending a string. Example:

```
mySocket.send("Hello".encode() + Client_name.encode())
```

Or:

```
mySocket.send(b"Hello" + Client_name.encode())
```