# How to convert a password into a hash value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a login system for my project and I need to use hashing for the users password, I am unsure how to hash a variable name and convert it into bytes to give a hex result for the password.

tried using:

```
hash_object = hashlib.md5(b(password))
```

and:

```
hash_object = hashlib.md5((password))
```

**Code**:

```
import hashlib

user = {}

username = input("What is your username? ")
password = input("What is your password? ")

hash_object = hashlib.md5((password))
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\loginsystem.py", line 8, in <module>
    hash_object = hashlib.md5((password))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: also - do not use md5 to hash passwords. see here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846 for better recommendations.

Comment: If you're just learning about security - fine. However if you're ever going to publish something to the public internet / actual users then do not roll your own authentication - leave it to the experts.

Comment: so its utf8 rightttt lol

Answer (score 1):

Encode the password string with the `.encode` method.

```
import hashlib

user = {}

username = input("What is your username? ")
password = input("What is your password? ")

hash_object = hashlib.md5(passsword.encode('utf8'))
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
```

---

I recommend this great thread that might clear some things up:

[What is the difference between a string and a byte string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried that but some reason this error message pops up

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/hash_function_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    hash_object = hashlib.md5(password.encode('uft-8'))
LookupError: unknown encoding: uft-8

Comment: THANK U SOOOO MUCH MY MAN

Comment: No problem, happy to help!