# What is Python's bytes type actually used for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, byte

Could somebody explain the general purpose of [the bytes type in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects), or give some examples where it is preferred over other data types?

I see that the advantage of [bytearrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects) over strings is their mutability, but what about bytes? So far, the only situation where I actually needed it was sending and receiving data through sockets; is there something else?

Answer (score 16):

Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between a string and a byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

In short, the bytes type is a sequence of bytes that have been encoded and are ready to be stored in memory/disk. There are many types of encodings (utf-8, utf-16, windows-1255), which all handle the bytes differently. The bytes object can be decoded into a str type.

The str type is a sequence of unicode characters. The str needs to be encoded to be stored, but is mutable and an abstraction of the bytes logic.

There is a strong relationship between `str` and `bytes`. `bytes` can be decoded into a `str`, and `str`s can be encoded into bytes.

You typically only have to use `bytes` when you encounter a string in the wild with a unique encoding, or when a library requires it. `str` , especially in python3, will handle the rest.

More reading [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3) and [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/strings-unicode-and-bytes-in-python-3-everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-27dc02ff2686)

Comment: Thanks, I know the difference between bytes and other types. I'm interested where they are used where strings can't be.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your comment after about 2 years. If you have any other comments, I'll be sure to get to them in 2023.

Comment: @pinwheel one example would a server and client sending messages to each other. The method `socket.recvfrom(bufsize[, flags])` returns (bytes, address)

Answer (score 0):

Sockets is a good case for using `bytes`.  Also you should use `bytes` to read/write binary data, like image or audio, from a file or a web API.  The `str` type is an immutable sequence of **character**, which is typically `UTF8` encoded.  Obviously if your data is not characters, then doing the `UTF8` encoding on it will be inefficient and could cause bugs.