# Difference between symbol's code in ord and bytes()

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I need to get the symbol's code in utf-8 and print symbol by this code. If I use `ord('Ц')` it returns 1062 and `chr(1062)` return a 'Ц', so it's all clear. But when I'm trying to do similar thing using `bytes('Ц', encoding='utf-8')`, it returns `b'\xd0\xa6'` though hex representation of 1062 is 0x426. How does it work? Why does it return two hex numbers, and value of these numbers are not equal to 1062?

Comment: UTF-8 != HEX...

Comment: You can learn more about the utf-8 encoding here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 TL;DR: utf-8 is a variable length encoding that won't match up with the hex representation of a number

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6224384/4739755) also helps explain the difference between bytes and string (character) encodings.

Comment: UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding. Characters in the range 0 to 127 are encoded using one byte (exactly the same as ASCII). The range 128 to 65535 uses two or three bytes. A fourth byte may be used to encode characters beyond that.

Comment: number `1062` is code in UNICODE, but `UTF-8` uses different codes. `byte` means values `0-255`, if something is bigger then 255 then `bytes()` keeps it as two or more values - and in `b'\xd0\xa6'` you have two values.

Comment: @furas Not 255 - `chr(128).encode('utf-8')` -> `b'\xc2\x80'` (two bytes).

Comment: @ekhumoro wrong, `bytes([128])` gives `b\x80`. But char with code `128` in `UNICODE`, doesn't have code `128` in UTF-8. It has code `49792` which gives `b'\xc2\x80'`

Comment: @furas All characters in the range 128-255 are encoded using two bytes in UTF-8. The byte-sequence `\x80` is not valid UTF-8 (try `b'\x80'.decode('utf-8')`). The expression `chr(128)` returns a unicode string (i.e. text), not bytes.

Comment: @ekhumoro but you didn't understand my previous comment. I was talking about `byte` and `bytes` - and why bytes display values bigger then 255 as two numbers and not one number like `0x426`. And it had nothing to do with `utf-8` which is different problem.

Comment: @furas But UTF-8 will produce *two bytes* for characters less than 256 - so your point is not entirely valid. Note that the OP is explicitly encoding the bytes as UTF-8.

Comment: @ekhumoro but I was talking about pure `byte` and `bytes` and not about `bytes` created by `utf`. BTW: when you encode to UTF then it replace `128` with `49792` and later it convert to bytes - so `bytes` never use value 128.

Comment: @furas You said:  "if something is bigger then 255 then bytes() keeps it as two or more values". This is not true - it depends on the encoding. There is no such thing as "pure bytes" when using `bytes()` with text strings.

Comment: @ekhumoro - you still doesn't understand that bytes gets `49792`, not `128` - and it display `49792` as hex. bytes doesn't convert value `128` to `49792`. If other encoding convert `128` to `128` then bytes will get `128` to display it as hex.

Comment: @ekhumoro `bytes()` is method to keep values as bytes - it doesn't have to be used to encode strings. You can create ie. `bytes([128, 255])` (`b'\x80\xff'`) and it has nothing to do with encoding. And this is what I called "pure bytes"

Comment: @furas This is about text strings (unicode), not byte arrays. The number of hex values in the output depends on the encoding. Thus `chr(169).encode('utf-8')` -> `b'\xc2\xa9'` (two bytes), but `chr(169).encode('latin1')` -> `b'\xa9'` (one byte). So this is about multi-byte versus single-byte encodings of non-ascii text strings.

Comment: @ekhumoro it is place for comment and comments can be more or less connected to code.