# How to resolve TypeError when migrating code to Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I moved my python scripts from 2.7 to 3 using 2to3 module, and now I am trying them out...Can some explain what I need to change here?

```
found_qr = None
while not found_qr:
    keep_alive(1,5)
    time.sleep(4)
    process = None
    stdout_list = None
    process = subprocess.Popen('grep -E -o ".Source QR CODE :.{0,65}" ' + latest_file + ' | tail -1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    stdout_list = process.communicate()
    stdout_list = stdout_list[0]
    if stdout_list.find("Source QR CODE") == -1:
        found_qr = None
    else:
        found_qr = 'found!'
```

I am getting this error:

```
if stdout_list.find("Source QR CODE") == -1:
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

any idea? thanks!

Update: Here is a similar issue I am seeing:

```
keep_alive(1,1)
process = subprocess.Popen('grep -E -o ".Source QR CODE :.{0,65}" ' + latest_file + ' | tail -1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
stdout_list = process.communicate()
qr_code = stdout_list[0].replace('Source QR CODE : ','')
qr_code = qr_code.replace(' ','')
qr_code = qr_code.replace('\n', '')
qr_code = str(qr_code)
```

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `stdout_list = process.communicate()` you get a list of `bytes`, so `stdout_list[0]` is a *bytes object*.

In `stdout_list.find("Source QR CODE")` you're trying to find a *string* in this *bytes object*, which won't work because [`bytes` is different from `str` in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string).

Since this string is constant, you can convert it to a `bytes` object easily:

```
stdout_list.find(b"Source QR CODE")  # note the `b` before the string literal
```

Or encode this string appropriately:

```
stdout_list.find("Source QR CODE".encode('ascii'))  # here you can use whatever encoding you need
```

As the error message tells you, you can search for "bytes-like objects" and integers, because a bytes object is actually a list of integers from 0 to 255:

```
>>> b'thing'  # this is a bytes object
b'thing'
>>> list(_)
[116, 104, 105, 110, 103]  # actually a bunch of integers (bytes)
>>> b'thing'.find(116)  # find a single byte
0
```

Comment: That seems to have worked...but can you help with this (similar issue):       
process = subprocess.Popen('grep -E -o ".Source QR CODE :.{0,65}" ' + latest_file + ' | tail -1', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
        stdout_list = process.communicate()
        qr_code = stdout_list[0].replace('Source QR CODE : ','')
        qr_code = qr_code.replace(' ','')
        qr_code = qr_code.replace('\n', '')
        qr_code = str(qr_code)

Comment: @cjg123, you can run your code through [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/2to3.html) first. It should convert most of the code to Python 3 automatically

Comment: I did, but a lot of it was not changed...why would that be?

Comment: @cjg123, well, it's not perfect. For example, it doesn't seem to be able to infer that `stdout_list` is a `bytes` object. Anyway, for each error message of this kind, you should add a prefix `b` to each string literal in that line. For example: `qr_code = stdout_list[0].replace('Source QR CODE : ','')` -> `qr_code = stdout_list[0].replace(b'Source QR CODE : ', b'')`

Comment: yeah, I just did that and it appears to be working. Thank you for your help (and yeah, it does not appear to be a perfect system, but a decent starting point).

Comment: Question: I am now being returned this in the 2nd part      b'a,555.55.7.38,22222,device-lab,..!1wdf336F3tN*'  ... whereas before I would just get back a string...Why?

Comment: @cjg123, actually, `qr_code = str(qr_code)` will result in `"b'thing'"`, not just `b'thing'`. Why? Well, Python did what you asked it to do - it returned the string _representation_ of that `bytes` object - the `"b'thing'"`, while you expected just `"thing"`, _but_ that would be a different operation - [decoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).