# in python is there a good way to get an inner subset of XML?

Tags: python, xml

i have some xml and i would like to get a subset of the inner xml
i have looked through docs and examples for ElementTree but have not really found a solution

Given the example below is there an easy way to achieve this?
original xml:

```
    <a>
        <b1>not interested</b1>
        <b2 key="not interested at all">
            <c key="i want this">
                <d1> the good stuff</d1>
                <d2> more good stuff </d2>
                <d3>
                    <e1 key="good">still good stuff</e1>
                </d3>
            </c>
        </b2>
    </a>
```

and i want to pull out some inner xml so result would be like:

```
<c key="i want this">
    <d1> the good stuff</d1>
    <d2> more good stuff </d2>
    <d3>
        <e1 key="good">still good stuff</e1>
    </d3>
</c>
```

Comment: Check [*this*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) out.

Comment: ive been through it  a few times, what am i missing?

Comment: There could be a [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) in your xml ? Can you open the original file and check if its identical to the Python input?

Comment: Also check [datacamps](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a solution using the [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module and the example XML you provided in your question.

See corresponding notes in code sample following.

1. **Create root element from the source XML text.**

   > The [`xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) function parses the provided XML string and returns an [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) instance.
2. **Use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query to locate the new root Element.**

   > The [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) function returns a *list* of matching Element objects from the source `Element` object.
   >
   > > **Since you are trying to establish a new root for your new XML document, this query *must* be designed to match one and only one element from the source document**, hence the extraction of `new_root` via `[0]`.  (Insert appropriate error handling here!)

The `ElementTree` module has limited [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but here is a breakdown of the query string:

`.//c`: Search for all `<c>` elements

`[@key='i want this']`: Filter found `<c>` elements and return only those with a `key` attribute matching `'i want this'`

3. **Encode new root Element to a Unicode string.**

   > The [`xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) function renders the provided `Element` and its children to XML text.  The `encoding="unicode"` is specified since the default encoding returns a [byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string/31322359#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20a%20byte%20string,is%20a%20sequence%20of%20characters.).

Code sample:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 0. Assign test XML text string.
    my_xml = '''<a>
        <b1>not interested</b1>
        <b2 key="not interested at all">
            <c key="i want this">
                <d1> the good stuff</d1>
                <d2> more good stuff </d2>
                <d3>
                    <e1 key="good">still good stuff</e1>
                </d3>
            </c>
        </b2>
    </a>'''
    # 1. Create root Element from the source XML text.
    root = ET.fromstring(my_xml)
    # 2. Use XPath query to locate the new root Element.
    new_root = root.findall(".//c[@key='i want this']")[0]
    # 3. Encode new root Element to a Unicode string.
    my_new_xml = ET.tostring(new_root, encoding="unicode")
    print(my_new_xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with lxml:

```
import lxml.html as lh
data ="""[your html above]"""

doc = lh.fromstring(data)
target = doc.xpath('.//c')
print(lh.tostring(target[0]).decode())
```

The output is your expected output.

Comment: both answers appear correct , gave the tick to the first in, thanks