# Regular expression is not working in python script

Tags: python, regex, python-re

the regular expression is not working. please find the below details.

```
cpu_pattern = re.compile('.*CPU.*(usr|user).*nice.*sys.*')

part = b'11:40:24 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle\n11:40:25 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.08      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.92'
```

**IF condition:**

```
if cpu_pattern.search(part): if cpu_usage == '': cpu_usage == part
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError('cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object')
```

Comment: As the error says, You `'cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object'`. Your search-pattern is a string, the `part` variable is bytes.

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Comment: convert `part` to `str`

Comment: part is one of the list value

Comment: use: `match = cpu_pattern.search(str(part))`

Comment: @ipj That doesn’t work. You need to *decode* the byte sequence.

Comment: Right, however  `cpu_pattern.search(str(part))' returns `<re.Match object; span=(14, 17), match='CPU'>` with no error the result is wrong. Use: `part.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: tp_count = len(time_points)
        xtick_label_stepsize = tp_count / 15
        if xtick_label_stepsize == 0:
            xtick_label_stepsize = 1
        self.x_data = range(tp_count)
        self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize)
        self.xtick_labels = [self.x_data[i] for i in self.xticks]                                           
                                                                                                                                  
       Error : range indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code to convert byte to string in python which will solve your issue:

```
part= part.decode("utf-8")
```

Put above code after `part` obejct

Output `print(part)`:

```
11:40:24 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle                         
11:40:25 AM     all      0.00      0.00      0.08      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     99.92
```

Answer (score 0):

[`part` is not a string, it’s a *byte sequence*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322359/1968). You now have two choices; which is more appropriate depends on how `part` was generated:

1. Perform byte-wise matching rather than string matching, by using a byte sequence pattern:

   ```
   cpu_pattern = re.compile(b'.*CPU.*(usr|user).*nice.*sys.*')
   ```
2. Decode the `parts` byte sequence using an appropriate encoding, e.g. UTF-8:

   ```
   parts_str = parts.decode('utf-8')
   ```

Comment: **cpu_usage += "\n" + part **                                                                                             Can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str