# Importance of Random Letters when Reading EXIF Information Via piexif

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, piexif

I am just getting into python and am specifically using Pillow and piexif to extract and edit EXIF data for bunch of jpegs that I have. I used piexif to extract and read the EXIF data information like ImageDescription, and noticed lots of fields have random letters in front; when I first pulled ImageDescription, it read b'Olympus.....' I edited the tag and when I output it now gave me, as a test, just test (no b or apostrophe's, and samples from piexif showed u's)

Anyone know the purpose of the apostrophe and/or the random letters?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that there are several letters that are used like u, r or b. If an r is found before the string, it becomes a string literal, and u and b are just encoding options.

Answer (score 0):

These are not "random letters". They signify [Unicode literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/) (`u` prefix), [raw literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) (`r`) and [bytestrings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6224384/453616) (`b`).