# Understanding the need of encoding and decoding in context to saving the strings on disk

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, string-decoding

I have read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string). I understand what a byte stream is (a stream of 1s and 0s), encoding is (a mapping from that stream to what characters that we humans understand) and decoding is (a reverse mapping from characters to corresponding bytes).

I still cannot reconcile the entire concept in my head. In the RAM we already have everything as bytes only. And I guess my interpreter is inherently using some decoding scheme to show me the characters corresponding to that bytes stream. What then do we mean by having to encode before saving to the disk? If my interpreter is using 'utf-8' to show us this text that I am typing and I ask it to save this text using 'cp-1252' have I changed the underlying bytes stream?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to see it.

On way: "Hello World!" could be encoded in different way. You want the semantic of the string: so a salutation and a target. But if you save to a UTF-8 file, you will have different values, as in a UTF-16LE file, or in a EBCDIC encoding.

E.g. `A` is 65 on ASCII encoding, but 193 in EBCDIC encoding (used e.g. by many IBM mainframes), 0 65 on a UTF-16 encoding (or 65 0). Etc. So when you save a number, you need to specify the encoding (as expected for the reader, so it may depend on file format).

But also libraries on a language could not handle all encodings (for all functions). Usually it is better to decode, using the standard libraries, and then encode when the data should go out. So you need to implement just encoding and decoding (e.g. for EBCDIC), and not all sorting, upper/lower case handling, is_digits, is_symbol, etc.

it is standard practice to divide semantic with real values. Or display with logic.  If you are a control freak, you can do all without decoding values. But it is error prone, and you should know so many details, that few people want to know.

An other example, do you need to know the real values of your data/strings? You have a number, it is encoded little-endian or big-endian? Or maybe as a float (e.g. JavaScript). We just know it, when we save data (e.g. to send in internet, we need a way to tell the ordering. Or when saving images: we tell the ordering, so on some machines, the bytes will be swapped, when reading a large number).

Or an other example: you take a selfies. You have an image, but you can save it as a PNG file, or a JPEG file: you will get very different files, with different values. But you know the encoding (fortunately, for such image files, the first bytes describe the format, and then few data about the encoding). For you it is enough to know that it is your image. But do you think computer will take the bytes of the two formats? Probably no. When you read the image, you will convert in a different encoding in memory (but you probably do not need to care about it): often a RGB (or RGBA) format, but how many bit per channel, or if there is some colour rendering (from profiles), you do not know [JPEG saves it as YCC]

Python has a stricter semantic view: you do not know how Python will encode the string. It may be 8bit: ASCII/Latin1, or 16-bit (UCS2), or 32-bit (UTF-32). It handles the internal encoding dynamically, according the most efficient way to store a string. You can still get a codepoint, a *for each character*, and many string/character function. Just then you encode a string, you have a fix sequence of numbers. On the string side you really do not know how strings are represented in memory. So this keep the two different parts of Unicode clearly separated: semantic value (description of all character), and the encoding/decoding (how to represent the values in bytes).

When you are handling a string in Python, you should just care about the semantic. The implementation (and so the physical layout of string in memory) is not your businesses, and Python can change it. (it changed it).

But with your example:

You may not get much of it, because recent standardisation: ASCII become nearly the only encoding for the most common Latin letters, and symbols. Latin-1 is compatible with ASCII, just extending from 7-bit to 8-bit. "Windows ANSI" uses Latin-1 and add characters on the non-allocated parts. Unicode based from Latin-1 (for first 256 characters). So you may see a character with a fixed number (or not available), but this was not the rule, also in early Windows.

So your *cp-1252* is for most characters compatible with UTF-8 (but few characters). But if you uses other encoding, you should do much a transcoding (changing from an encoding to an other). But usually you do this just when you save: you keep the internal encoding, but you do a copy to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

A byte is 8 bits, whether it is in RAM, on disk, or on the wire.

A bit is the "atom" of computer data.  A byte is the "molecule", except that there is only one kind of byte.

A bit is the smallest unit of information in computers.  It is usually said to represent 0 or 1, or OFF or ON.

Whether you "interpret" a byte as a number (0 to 255), a signed number (-128 to +127), an "ascii" character, like the characters I am typing, depends on what you (or the computer) does with the byte.  Or a byte can be part of a bigger number, one that requires several bytes to represent.

Because there are too many "letters" or "characters" (especially in Chinese), to fit in a byte, there is the additional concept of a "character" *may* be composed of multiple bytes.  UTF-8 is the main standard today.  Giacomo discusses several less-common encodings that say what "character" is represented by a byte (or bytes).  Remember, each byte is composed of 8 bits.

English letters and numbers and some punctuation is represented (encoded) in bytes in the same way for Ascii, Latin1, cp-1252, and UTF-8 (and *some* other encodings).  But as soon as you get into European accented letters, the encodings diverge.

A common thing you may hear of is to represent one byte as two hexadecimal digits.