# Python3 str to bytes conversion issues

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte, encode

In python 3.8.5 I try to convert some bytes to string and then string to bytes:

```
>>> a=chr(128)
>>> a
'\x80'
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

But when I try to do conversion back:

```
>>> a.encode()
b'\xc2\x80'
```

What is \xc2 bytes? Why does it appear?

Thanks for any response!

Answer (score 0):

This a UTF-8 encoding, so the `\xc2` comes from here, take a look [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/09/09/how-utf-8-works/).

In a Python string, `\x80` means [Unicode codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) #128 (Padding Character). When we encode that codepoint in UTF-8, it takes two bytes.

The original ASCII encoding only had 128 different characters, there are many thousands of Unicode codepoints, and a single byte can only represent 256 different values. A lot of computing is based on ASCII, and we’d like that stuff to keep working, but we need non-English-speakers to be able to use computers too, so we need to be able to represent their characters.

The answer is UTF-8, a scheme that encodes the first 128 Unicode code points (0-127, the ASCII characters) as a single byte – so text that only uses those characters is completely compatible with ASCII. The next 1920 characters, containing the most common non-English characters (U+80 up to U+7FF) are spread across two bytes.

So, in exchange for being slightly less efficient with some characters that could fit in a one-byte encoding (such as \x80), we gain the ability to represent every character from every written language.

For more reading, try this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

For example if you want to remove the `\xc2` try to encode your string as *latin-1*

```
a=chr(128)
print(a)

#'\x80'

print(a.encode())

#b'\xc2\x80'

a.encode('latin-1')

#b'\x80'
```

Comment: Hi @EvgeniyNekrasov if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, also take a look to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/315993) for more details.