# Python - Store cryptography keys in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, mariadb

Working on a "Password Saver" and will be using the module "cryptography" to encrypt the passwords. I need to save the key you generate from cryptography in the database as well, but I am not sure how you actually do this.

Done some google searches myself and it seems to be called a "byte string"? Not really sure what it is though.

This is what I have currently:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    database='password_saver'
)

cursor = db.cursor()

key = Fernet.generate_key()

cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO `encryption`(`encryption_key`) VALUES ({key})")
```

With that code I am getting this error:
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'cryptographys key is here')' at line 1`

Not sure if there is a specific data type I need to use for SQL or if it is something I need to do in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use: `key = Fernet.generate_key().decode()`, and change the query to a parameterised query.

---

There are two key elements in play here:

- What is a byte string?
- SQL injection

---

#### Byte String:

Given the rule that everything in a computer is a number, a 'byte string' is just that, it's a string of bytes - which is not human readable. However, the reason we can read `b'my string'` is because Python is doing us a favour in converting the bytes back into a readable string. But under the hood, it's just a string of bytes.

[Further (interesting) reading on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322359/6340496)

As for converting the byte string into a string (`str`), something MySQL can store in a `VARCHAR` field, it's as simple as:

```
b'my string'.decode()
```

So in your case, the key will be:

```
key = Fernet.generate_key().decode()
```

**Another option:**

Or, if you want to store the raw byte string in the database, you can convert your `encryption_key` column to a `BLOB` data type. This is a 'Binary Large OBject' field, used to store bytes. However, when it comes time to use the key value, you'll have to convert it into a string. So might as well do the conversion up front, and just store the string.

---

#### SQL Injection:

[Please read up on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), I won't get into it here - but it's important.

The short story is **use parameterised queries**.

Change this:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO `encryption` (`encryption_key`) VALUES ({key})")
```

To this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `encryption` (`encryption_key`) VALUES (%s)", (key,))
```