# What the below literal means in python?

Tags: python

The literal values expressed in python as

'b"8.23"' and 'b"1.25"'

These are expressions specific to python.

Comment: This is a byte literal (in Python 3). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a string and a byte string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)

Comment: Yes awesoon and gerriet

Answer (score 1):

The `b` character before a string produces a variable of `byte` type instead of `string` type. You may read about this definition [on the official website](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/).

Answer (score 1):

The character 'b' shows that the given variable is of type byte, not string.

Let me distinguish between string and byte definitions to make it clear,

```
str = '...' 
# Above literals is sequence of Unicode characters (Latin-1, UCS-2 or UCS-4)
bytes = b'...' 
# Above literals are sequence of octets (integers between 0 and 255)
```

)

Comment: Perfect answer,
Thanks All of you.