# Why 'list(bytestring)' is displaying list of decimal values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, unicode

I have read that in Python, a **[bytestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string)** is a **sequence of bytes**

To completely understand the above statement,  I have written the following code:

```
s = 'hello'
b = s.encode()
list(b)
```

The above code is returning following output:

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

My question is why `b` here is returning **sequence of decimal values** instead of returning **sequence of bytes**?

Can you please help me understand this concept using some example?

Comment: A byte is just a number between 0 and 255

Comment: Python represents *a* byte as an integer in the range 0..255.

Comment: If `byte is a number between 0 and 255` then what is the difference between a byte and `unicode code point`?

Comment: The range of unicode codepoints is considerably larger than 0-255 ...

Comment: Neither a byte nor a unicode code point *are* integers. They are *represented* as integers. That doesn't make them equivalent. Just because Jason down the street is 23 years old and Becky from work has 23 Dollars doesn't mean Jason's age is Becky's cash.

Comment: It's simply a design decision.  The developers could have made `bytes` iterators return length-1 `bytes` objects and they could have made `str` iterators return `int` objects representing Unicode code points.  But `bytes` typically represent numbers (data) and `str` typically represent text, so it made more sense to the developers to implement it they way they did.

Comment: can you please help me understand this concept using some example?