# Failing to parse email from Gmail correcty because of `\r\n`

Tags: python, gmail-api

I have a simple email in Gmail that looks like this:

```
Hi all

@alice - please prepare XXX for tomorrow
@bob - please prepare YYY for tomorrow

best,
Z
```

and I would like to fetch it, parse it and split by newline, so I would get a list of 5 elements:

```
['Hi all','@alice ...', '@bob ...', 'best,','Z']
```

but for some reason inside the sentence I get `\r\n` which makes me break the line into 2 lines although in the original email there wasn't new line.

I parse it as following (after getting the proper credentials)

```py
txt = service.users().messages().get(userId=user.email, id=email_msg['id']).execute()
payload = txt["payload"]
headers = payload["headers"]

parts = payload.get("parts")[0]
data = parts["body"]["data"]
data = data.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/")
decoded_message = str(base64.b64decode(data), "utf-8")
split = decoded_message.splitlines()
final_split = list(filter(None, split))
```

but then the message I get looks like this:

```
Hi all\r\n\r\n@alice - please prepare XXX\r\nfor tomorrow\r\n@bob - please prepare YYY for tomorrow\\r\nr\nbest,\n\rZ
```

so if I split by `\r\n` or `\n` I get invalid result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested in the comment by Daniel, I used the HTML data in order to extract the message correctly:

I defined the `HTML` parser:

````
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from io import StringIO

def extract_text(html_text: str) -> str:
    class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.reset()
            self.strict = False
            self.convert_charrefs = True
            self.text = StringIO()

        def handle_data(self, d):
            self.text.write(d)

        def get_data(self):
            return self.text.getvalue()

    def strip_tags(html):
        s = MLStripper()
        s.feed(html)
        return s.get_data()

    cleaned_html_text = html_text.replace('</div>', '\n</div>').replace('\r\n', '')\
        .replace('<br>', '\n').replace('\xa0', ' ')
    return strip_tags(cleaned_html_text)```
````

and then run it on the `HTML`:

```
parts = payload.get("parts")[1] # take the HTML part
data = parts["body"]["data"]
data = data.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/")
decoded_message = str(base64.b64decode(data), "utf-8")
extracted_message = extract_text(html_text=decoded_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you decode the data using `b64decode()` you don't get a string, instead you get a byte string. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string) an excellent explanation of the difference. Before trying to parse the message you have to convert it into a regular string.

You can do this by running  [`.decode("utf-8")`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_decode.htm). Then you can just use `.splitlines()` to split the message.

```py
txt = service.users().messages().get(userId=user.email, id=email_msg['id']).execute()
payload = txt["payload"]
headers = payload["headers"]

parts = payload.get("parts")[0]
data = parts["body"]["data"]
data = data.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/")
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)

decoded_message = decoded_data.decode("utf-8") # decodes the byte string

split = decode_message.splitlines() # splits the message into a list

final_split = list(filter(None, split)) # this removes the blank lines
```

Running `.decode()` on the message will change it from this:

```
Hi all\r\n\r\n@alice - please prepare XXX\r\nfor tomorrow\r\n@bob - please prepare YYY for tomorrow\\r\nr\nbest,\n\rZ
```

To the original message:

```
Hi all

@alice - please prepare XXX for tomorrow
@bob - please prepare YYY for tomorrow

best,
Z
```

Then after `.splitlines()` you will get this list:

```
['Hi all', '', '@alice...', '@bob...', '', 'best,', 'Z']
```

Note that there are blank strings that correspond to the blank lines. To get rid of them you can run the last line `final_split = list(filter(None, split))`, which will give you what you're looking for. There are other [methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-empty-strings-from-list-of-strings/) as well:

```
['Hi all', '@alice...', '@bob...', 'best,', 'Z']
```

By the way, I did not install `BeautifulSoup` for this, but if you want to use it you probably want to add it after you decode the byte string.

Comment: thanks for the specified answer! I tried adding `decoded_data.decode("utf-8")` after `b64decode`, but it did not change anything - the `\r\n` are still there

Comment: Can you post the modified code?

Comment: as you suggested, after `decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)` I added `decoded_message = decoded_data.decode("utf-8")`. But I still see '\r\n'

Comment: That's odd, you're using Python 3, right? Are you running the data through BeautifulSoup before trying to decode it? It's possible that the soup turns it into a normal string without parsing out the escape sequence first.

Comment: Using python `3.9.10`. I use `BeautifulSoup` after decoding.

Comment: How about doing it in one go. Try `decoded_data=str(base64.b64decode(data), "utf-8")`. You can skip the `.decode()` since that should do it right away.

Comment: Same result. It seems  that Gmail somehow add random `\r\n` in the emails

Comment: It's not really Gmail adding it but the result of the Python function. Can you edit your original post with your current code? Maybe there's something missing.

Comment: added the latest code

Comment: It's strange. I pretty much copied your code to test and it works for me. We can try to track down the issue at the source. Try to get the base64 email in the `data` variable and plug it into https://www.base64decode.org/ instead of using Python. Is the output the same with the escape sequences?

Comment: As you suggested I checked the data in `base64decode.org`: `SGkgQXJpZWwgaG93IGFyZSB5b3U/DQpJ4oCZZCBsaWtlIHlvdSB0byBjaGVjayB0aGUgY3VzdG9tZXJzIHNpdGUgdG9tb3Jyb3cgYXQgOSBBTSBJ4oCZZCBsaWtlIHlvdSB0bw0KY2hlY2sgdGhlIGN1c3RvbWVycyBJ4oCZZCBsaWtlIHlvdSB0byBjaGVjayB0aGUgY3VzdG9tZXJzDQo=`. I see the line breaks after `like you to`, but in the email I do not have new line there

Comment: The reason for that newline is that the message is also encoded in [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) format, which adds line breaks every roughly 76 characters. Python has a `quopri` module to decode this but in my tests I was unsuccessful trying to remove that line. I have another suggestion, `parts = payload.get("parts")[0]` gets the message in plain text, but `parts = payload.get("parts")[1]` gets it in HTML format, which you can try to run through BeautifulSoup. Maybe this was your original purpose? You'll still have to decode the byte string, by the way.

Comment: I tried to do to parse  `payload.get("parts")[1]` as `HTML` but without any success

Comment: Why? What went wrong in that case?

Comment: The decoded `html` looks like this: `'<div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div>Hi Ariel how are you?</div><div>I’d \r\nlike you to check the customers site tomorrow at 9 AM I’d like you to \r\ncheck the customers I’d like you to check the customers<br></div><div>Also we need you to check with the client if she&#39;s available on the next Monday morning to meet with us on the site<div class="gmail-yj6qo"></div><div class="gmail-adL"><br></div><div class="gmail-adL">Best,</div><div class="gmail-adL">Bob<br></div></div></div></div></div></div>\r\n'`. I still get `\r\n`.

Comment: It's strange because in my environment decoding the string worked with my tests and even with the sample base64 string that you provided. Unfortunately I'm not an expert on this so you may want to post another question asking why the python `decode` would not work for you.