# How to Filter 2 parameters with scatterplot and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I need to separate some data that I got. I'm using pandas DataFrame in order to do this.

Here is the code before my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
```

```
arquivo_arff = arff.loadarff(r"/content/Rice_MSC_Dataset.arff")
dados = pd.DataFrame(arquivo_arff[0])
```

```
dados = dados[['MINOR_AXIS', 'MAJOR_AXIS', 'CLASS']]
```

I've already done a scatterplot graph with 5 parameters to analyze with this code (0 filters):

```
sns.scatterplot(
    data=dados, 
    x="MINOR_AXIS", 
    y="MAJOR_AXIS", 
    hue="CLASS")
plt.show()
```

My problem: I need to filter only the species b'Basmati' and  b'Ipsala', but i'm unnable to do that, I don't know why.

The "CLASS" parameters are: b'Basmati',b'Arborio',b'Jasmine',b'Ipsala',bKaracadag'

But, in the ".arff" file that I used, the names are only "Basmati,Arborio,Jasmine,Ipsala,Karacadag"

What I've tried:
Filter only this two species, with this code:

```
dados = dados[dados['CLASS'].isin(["" "b'Arborio'" "", "" "b'Ipsala'" ""])]
```

Didn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does using `.isin(["Arborio", "Ipsala"])]` or `.isin([b"Arborio", b"Ipsala"])]` work?

Comment: `.isin([b"Arborio", b"Ipsala"])]` Worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The system has somewhere shown to you that the class parameters are `b'Basmati'`, `b'Arborio'`, `b'Jasmine'`, `b'Ipsala'` and `b'Karacadag'`. However, this does not mean that the parameters are actually these characters inside a string. These are the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) representations of the strings that contain the parameters. Apparently, these string are [byte strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string), which are created by placing a b in front of the string, hence the strange repr representations.

The solution to your problem is to provide the strings, `"Arborio"` and `"Ipsala"`, to pandas as a byte string, by placing a b in front of them:

```py
dados = dados[dados['CLASS'].isin([b"Arborio", b"Ipsala"])]
```