# How to set same encoding in Python String as when reading it from file

Tags: python, aws-lambda, encoding

I'm building an AWS Lambda to generate a JWT from a Pem. The example I'm using is taken from this link:

https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-json-web-token-jwt-for-a-github-app

When I read the pem from a file, everything works ok. This is the code that does the job:

```
# Open PEM
with open(pem, 'rb') as pem_file:
    signing_key = jwt.jwk_from_pem(pem_file.read())
```

However, I need to get the content of the pem file from an AWS secret. Therefore, this is the code that I'm using:

```
# get PEM from AWS secret
secret =  get_secret()
signing_key = jwt.jwk_from_pem(secret)
```

When I run this code, I get the error below:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 19, in handler\n    signing_key = jwt.jwk_from_pem(secret)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/jwt/jwk.py\", line 405, in jwk_from_pem\n    return jwk_from_bytes(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/jwt/jwk.py\", line 384, in jwk_from_bytes\n    return jwk_from_private_bytes(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/jwt/jwk.py\", line 328, in wrapper\n    return func(content, loader, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/jwt/jwk.py\", line 345, in jwk_from_private_bytes\n    privkey = private_loader(content, password, backend)  # type: ignore[operator]  # noqa: E501\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py\", line 24, in load_pem_private_key\n    return ossl.load_pem_private_key(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py\", line 949, in load_pem_private_key\n    return self._load_key(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py\", line 1169, in _load_key\n    mem_bio = self._bytes_to_bio(data)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py\", line 630, in _bytes_to_bio\n    data_ptr = self._ffi.from_buffer(data)\n"
  ]
}
```

It seems like for some reason, when I read the pem from the file, it has the correct encoding. However, when I get a String from the AWS Secret with the same value, it doesn't like the encoding.

Any suggestions?

-------------------------------EDIT----------------------------
Here's the get_secret function

```
def get_secret():

    secret_name = "pem"
    region_name = "eu-west-1"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        # For a list of exceptions thrown, see
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
        raise e

    # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
    secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    return (secret['pem'])
```

Comment: Where is `get_secret` defined? What is returned from it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about encoding at all - so far. Hint: where the code says `with open(pem, 'rb') as pem_file:`, what do you think is the effect of the `b` in `'rb'`? What *type* do you expect from the `pem_file.read()` call?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's a function that reads an AWS secret and returns a String.

Comment: Strings do not have an associated encoding. Python strings are fundamentally sequences of Unicode code points.

Comment: Does `get_secret` return a `str`? If so, you need to convert it into a `bytes` using `.encode`. This function evidently expects a `bytes` object and not a `str`. You _will_ need to choose an encoding to perform this conversion, so that depends on what `jwk_from_pem` expects.

Comment: @shadowtalker If you write an answer telling me how to do it and it works, I can give you the points

Comment: @Andres did you write the `get_secret` function? I can't answer until I know what it returns.

Comment: If the question is "how do I decode the `get_secret` result to bytes?", the canonical duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435. If you generally are confused about the distinction between strings and `bytes` objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/. If the question is "what encoding should I use?", that depends: **if the `pem_file` contents actually represent text**, then use the encoding that that file uses. You need to figure out that encoding; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220. Otherwise, *we need more information*.

Comment: @shadowtalker I added the function to the question

Comment: Aha. So the next issue is: *what does the documentation say*, about the JSON result that comes from `client.get_secret_value`? For example, does it say that the `SecretString` key contains a string with a particular encoding? Maybe it says that it represents binary data, using an encoding such as Base64, or as a hex dump? Something else? It's not possible for people to just tell you how to "decode" or otherwise interpret arbitrary data; the correct way depends on how the data is formatted/structured, which should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I guess if you want to answer the question you can look at the boto3 documentation

Comment: The documentation tells me that the corresponding string is "The decrypted secret value, if the secret value was originally provided as a string or through the Secrets Manager console. If this secret was created by using the console, then Secrets Manager stores the information as a JSON structure of key/value pairs." - well; *that's the problem*; if you are storing a secret that you need to use as a binary value later, you should *store a binary value in the first place*. After all, I see no guarantee here that the PEM data you need to store, *sensibly represents text in the first place*.

Answer (score 2):

A PEM file [contains plain text that represents binary data using base64 encoding](https://www.lifewire.com/pem-file-4147928). It is, therefore, effectively using ASCII encoding, or any ASCII-transparent encoding: it should only contain [the text characters used by Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which are all in the ASCII range, and it should represent those in the underlying file with one byte each. The `jwt.jwk_from_pem` interface apparently expects a `bytes` object; per the example in the linked documentation, this should be the raw data in the PEM file (i.e., even though it is still Base64-encoded; the library will take care of decoding that, despite that it expects binary rather than text data).

The stored secret, therefore, should be in a compatible format.

Since Base64 uses only ASCII characters, it will work fine to store textual data in the secret store, and read the `['SecretString']` from the response. This result [is](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager/client/get_secret_value.html) "The decrypted secret value, if the secret value was originally provided as a string or through the Secrets Manager console.". So, by providing a string that contains a Base64-representation of binary data (i.e., consists of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, digits, `+`, `/` and `=` - the latter used for padding), the secret store will store a usable value. To use it, we simply decode that string to binary using *any ASCII-compatible encoding* - such as, well, `'ascii'` - and proceed as before.

Alternately, the secret store can store binary data, and the client can check the `['SecretBinary']` key of the JSON response. However, in this case, "The response parameter represents the binary data as a base64-encoded string." In other words, the binary data (that happens to consist of ASCII representations of Base64 data) is base-64 encoded in the result JSON (*again*). The client code would need to decode that.

Comment: Your answer gave me a couple of ideas to test, but not a solution to the problem.