# IDNA Encode Adding Apostrophes and letter B?

Tags: python, punycode

I am using the IDNA library to encode/decode unicide domain names but when I encode a domain name, it adds apostrophes either side of the string and prepends the letter b?

For example:

```
import idna
print(idna.encode('español.com'))
```

Output: `b'xn--espaol-zwa.com'`

Expected output: `xn--espaol-zwa.com`

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious but not sure how to get to the bottom of this.

My expected output is reinforced by the fact if I *decode* it:

```
print(idna.decode('xn--espaol-zwa.com'))
```

I get the original domain: `español.com`

Comment: `encode()` returns a byte string, not a character string.

Comment: You can even see this in the example on the [homepage](https://pypi.org/project/idna/)

Comment: If you want to convert the byte string to a string, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224052/fnord) explain what you're seeing.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the pointers - I just expected encode/decode to only input/output the same format so it was throwing me, especially as I'm used to the PHP IDNA function which just outputs character strings!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any newbies like me looking for a simple solution to this, as @Barmer has pointed out, the IDNA package outputs a byte string even if you feed in a character string.

If you want a string, you can chain UTF-8 decoding thus:

```
idna.encode('español.com').decode('utf-8')
```

**Outputs a character string of :** xn--espaol-zwa.com

idna.decode will correctly decode this back to español.com without any further treatment needed.