# What's the difference between a byte stream and a byte string?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, bytestream

From the [DocuSign documentation on documents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/), "when you add a document file to an envelope, the DocuSign platform converts it to PDF and stores it as base64-encoded ASCII" and then in [REST API doc for `getDocument`](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/), "by default, the response is the PDF file as a **byte stream**... By using the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header in the request, you can obtain the PDF file encoded in base64." (emphasis mine)

This is what I understand thus far:

- When you download a document from DocuSign, you've to decode it back to its binary representation either with base64 or "byte stream" in order to save it to disk or provide it to another service that expects a `Buffer`. In NodeJS, which is how I'm interacting with DocuSign, this looks as follows:

  - `Buffer.from(pdfContent, "base64")`, assuming you downloaded the base64-encoded PDF.
  - `Buffer.from(pdfContent, "binary")` ([`binary` is an alias to `latin1`<sup>1</sup>), assuming you downloaded the "byte stream" PDF.
- When you download a document from DocuSign, you download the entire file at once and therefore it's not being *streamed*. In both cases, you're simply getting a whole string from DocuSign, not chunks of bytes.

The use of the term "byte stream" is what confuses me here because DocuSign isn't streaming the file (e.g., as I understand it streaming implies consuming from/writing to a resource chunk by chunk instead of as a whole). Assuming I'm correct, then a better term is [byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322359/10824322). Hence my questions:

- Is the term **byte stream** being used interchangeably with **byte string** here?
- At least in NodeJS, you need to decode the "byte stream" with `binary` (or `latin1`). Thus, is DocuSign using "byte stream" as the term for "binary code that must be decoded using the character encoding `latin1`"?

---

1. [From NodeJS Buffer docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings): "`'binary'`: Alias for `'latin1'`. The name of this encoding can be very misleading, as all of the encodings listed here convert between strings and binary data. For converting between strings and Buffers, typically `'utf8'` is the right choice."

Comment: @KJ Your last sentence is quite poignant, and at the heart of naming in Computer Science. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

The response is the file as a byte string, it is not a JSON response.

You are correct, the right terminology is byte string, not byte stream. We'll get the docs updated.

If you download as a byte string, it won't be encoded. It will be in binary. If your client can't handle that, then download with base64 encoding and then decode to binary.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks, Larry! *"If you download as a byte string, it won't be encoded. It will be in binary."* This doesn't seem to be the case, at least for the NodeJS SDK. At day-job, we tried passing the byte string as-is to the Box API and the PDF documents wouldn't open. It wasn't until we realized that we needed to decode the byte string with `binary`/`latin1` into a buffer, i.e., `Buffer.from(byteString, "binary")`.

Comment: Btw your comment has clarified my question the DocuSign API, however I won't choose it as an answer just in case someone wants to answer the question of byte string vs byte stream. Thanks!