# Manually converting unicode codepoints into UTF-8 and UTF-16

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have a university programming exam coming up, and one section is on unicode.

I have checked all over for answers to this, and my lecturer is useless so that’s no help, so this is a last resort for you guys to possibly help.

The question will be something like:

> The string 'mЖ丽' has these unicode codepoints `U+006D`, `U+0416` and
>   `U+4E3D`, with answers written in hexadecimal, manually encode the
>   string into UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated as I am trying to get my head round this.

Comment: Did you try to write a program that converts a UTF-8 string to a UTF-16 string and then manually compare the output (UTF-16) and input (UTF-8)?

Comment: I have played around with several coded converters, but im still at a miss as to how i actually do it manually with a pen and paper, as thats all we will have in the exam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does UTF-8 "variable-width encoding" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543613/how-does-utf-8-variable-width-encoding-work)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Wow. On the one hand I'm thrilled to know that university courses are teaching to the reality that character encodings are hard work, but actually knowing the UTF-8 encoding rules sounds like expecting a lot. (Will it help students [pass the Turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)?)

The clearest description I've seen so far for the rules to encode UCS codepoints to UTF-8 are from the `utf-8(7)` manpage on many Linux systems:

```
Encoding
   The following byte sequences are used to represent a
   character.  The sequence to be used depends on the UCS code
   number of the character:

   0x00000000 - 0x0000007F:
       0xxxxxxx

   0x00000080 - 0x000007FF:
       110xxxxx 10xxxxxx

   0x00000800 - 0x0000FFFF:
       1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

   0x00010000 - 0x001FFFFF:
       11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

   [... removed obsolete five and six byte forms ...]

   The xxx bit positions are filled with the bits of the
   character code number in binary representation.  Only the
   shortest possible multibyte sequence which can represent the
   code number of the character can be used.

   The UCS code values 0xd800–0xdfff (UTF-16 surrogates) as well
   as 0xfffe and 0xffff (UCS noncharacters) should not appear in
   conforming UTF-8 streams.
```

It might be easier to remember a 'compressed' version of the chart:

Initial bytes starts of mangled codepoints start with a `1`, and add padding `1+0`. Subsequent bytes start `10`.

```
0x80      5 bits, one byte
0x800     4 bits, two bytes
0x10000   3 bits, three bytes
```

You can derive the ranges by taking note of how much *space* you can fill with the bits allowed in the new representation:

```
2**(5+1*6) == 2048       == 0x800
2**(4+2*6) == 65536      == 0x10000
2**(3+3*6) == 2097152    == 0x200000
```

I know *I* could remember the rules to derive the chart easier than the chart itself. Here's hoping you're good at remembering rules too. :)

**Update**

Once you have built the chart above, you can convert input Unicode codepoints to UTF-8 by finding their range, converting from hexadecimal to binary, inserting the bits according to the rules above, then converting back to hex:

```
U+4E3E
```

This fits in the `0x00000800 - 0x0000FFFF` range (`0x4E3E < 0xFFFF`), so the representation will be of the form:

```
   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

`0x4E3E` is `100111000111110b`. Drop the bits into the `x` above (start from the right, we'll fill in missing bits at the start with `0`):

```
   1110x100 10111000 10111110
```

There is an `x` spot left over at the start, fill it in with `0`:

```
   11100100 10111000 10111110
```

Convert from [bits to hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Binary_conversion):

```
   0xE4 0xB8 0xBE
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for your help. The content on the course is good, cannot say the same for the lecturers teaching it tho. So for example. I have 'm' which is unicode codepoint 'u+006D' which i think lies in: 0x00000000 - 0x0000007F:
       0xxxxxxx. Im still a little confused as where to go from here

Comment: @Ryan, the _ascii_ range (`0--127` aka `0x0--0x7F`) is easy -- they self-represent. So your `u+006D` is just `01101101b`. :) (Which I got with my calculator, because I'm lazy. Hex-to-bin by hand isn't horrible though, you can write a translation table by hand at the start of the test and re-use it each time you need it. :)

Comment: @sarnold is it always 01101101 for everthing that lies between 0x0 - 0x7F? or was there more of a process to go from U+006D to 01101101b. Where did you get the b from?

Comment: @Ryan, sorry :) The `01101101b` was specific to your input `u+006D`. That's just `0x6D` in binary. (I included the `b` at the end to signify `binary` -- numbers starting with a leading `0` are sometimes meant to be [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers).) Everything between `0` and `0x7F` requires only seven bits to represent, so the leading `0` in the rules is just re-stating that the ascii range remains unchanged in UTF-8, one of its prime selling points.

Comment: Also the answer needs to be hexadecimal

Comment: for example, the unicode codepoint 'U+4E3E' has the utf-8 hexidecimal value of 'e4 b8 be'. How on earth does one get from U+4E3E to e4 b8 be? :|

Comment: @Ryan, I added a specific example

Comment: Wow, what a brilliant answer, thats amazing, thank you so much, you taught me over the internet what my lecturer couldn't do in a year. Any hints for 16 and 32 utfs? Brilliant, thankyou so so much. will give you top answer definatly

Comment: @Ryan, [Wikipedia's article on UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2#Code_points_U.2B10000..U.2B10FFFF) is pretty good about the conversion, it even looks _easier_ than UTF-8 but with the caveat that there is both big-endian and little-endian variants of UTF-16. [UTF-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-32) looks like a simple subset of UCS-4, where the not-yet-defined codepoints are ignored in UTF-32. (Sounds like committee-speak more than useful knowledge, to me.)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again. brilliant. Love the Stack Overflow community

Comment: Thanks for the Turkey test reference!  I was not aware of that!

Comment: Thanks for spelling out the symmetry 5 bit + 1 byte, 4 bits + 2 byte, ..., 1 bit + 5 bytes. Didn't spot that one myself, but now I will never forget UTF-8 encoding!

Comment: This answer is wrong, UTF-8 cannot use more than 4 bytes anymore (it was different some time ago).

Comment: @PatrykGołębiowski. thanks, I can't believe I've been wrong for so long.

Comment: Unicode is limited to 0x1FFFFF, which is 21 bits. there are no 5 or 6 byte codepoint sequences in Unicode...

Comment: @MarcusJ, thanks for the reminder, I never got around to removing the obsolete data after Patryk notified me.

Comment: great answer, very detailed

Answer (score 53):

The descriptions on Wikipedia for [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) are good:

Procedures for your example string:

#### UTF-8

UTF-8 uses up to 4 bytes to represent Unicode codepoints.  For the 1-byte case, use the following pattern:

> 1-byte UTF-8 = 0xxxxxxx<sub>bin</sub> = 7 bits = 0-7F<sub>hex</sub>

The initial byte of 2-, 3- and 4-byte UTF-8 start with 2, 3 or 4 one bits, followed by a zero bit.  Follow on bytes always start with the two-bit pattern `10`, leaving 6 bits for data:

> 2-byte UTF-8 = 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx<sub>bin</sub> = 5+6(11) bits = 80-7FF<sub>hex</sub>
> 3-byte UTF-8 = 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx<sub>bin</sub> = 4+6+6(16) bits = 800-FFFF<sub>hex</sub>
> 4-byte UTF-8 = 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx<sub>bin</sub> = 3+6+6+6(21) bits = 10000-10FFFF<sub>hex</sub><sup>†</sup>
>
> <sup>†</sup>Unicode codepoints are undefined beyond 10FFFF<sub>hex</sub>.

Your codepoints are U+006D, U+0416 and U+4E3D requiring 1-, 2- and 3-byte UTF-8 sequences, respectively.  Convert to binary and assign the bits:

> U+006D = 1101101<sub>bin</sub> = **0**1101101<sub>bin</sub> = 6D<sub>hex</sub>
> U+0416 = 10000 010110<sub>bin</sub> = **110**10000 **10**010110<sub>bin</sub> = D0 96<sub>hex</sub>
> U+4E3D = 0100 111000 111101<sub>bin</sub> = **1110**0100 **10**111000 **10**111101<sub>bin</sub> = E4 B8 BD<sub>hex</sub>

Final byte sequence:

> 6D D0 96 E4 B8 BD

or if nul-terminated strings are desired:

> 6D D0 96 E4 B8 BD 00

#### UTF-16

UTF-16 uses 2 or 4 bytes to represent Unicode codepoints.  Algorithm:

> U+0000 to U+D7FF uses 2-byte 0000<sub>hex</sub> to D7FF<sub>hex</sub>
> U+D800 to U+DFFF are invalid codepoints reserved for 4-byte UTF-16
> U+E000 to U+FFFF uses 2-byte E000<sub>hex</sub> to FFFF<sub>hex</sub>
>
> U+10000 to U+10FFFF uses 4-byte UTF-16 encoded as follows:
>
> 1. Subtract 10000<sub>hex</sub> from the codepoint.
> 2. Express result as 20-bit binary.
> 3. Use the pattern 110110xxxxxxxxxx 110111xxxxxxxxxx<sub>bin</sub> to encode the upper- and lower- 10 bits into two 16-bit words.

Using your codepoints:

> U+006D = 006D<sub>hex</sub>
> U+0416 = 0416<sub>hex</sub>
> U+4E3D = 4E3D<sub>hex</sub>

Now, we have one more issue.  Some machines store the two bytes of a 16-bit word least significant byte first (so-called little-endian machines) and some store most significant byte first (big-endian machines).  UTF-16 uses the codepoint U+FEFF (called the byte order mark or BOM) to help a machine determine if a byte stream contains big- or little-endian UTF-16:

> big-endian = FE FF 00 6D 04 16 4E 3D
> little-endian = FF FE 6D 00 16 04 3D 4E

With nul-termination, U+0000 = 0000<sub>hex</sub>:

> big-endian = FE FF 00 6D 04 16 4E 3D 00 00
> little-endian = FF FE 6D 00 16 04 3D 4E 00 00

Since your instructor didn't give a codepoint that required 4-byte UTF-16, here's one example:

> U+1F031 = 1F031<sub>hex</sub> - 10000<sub>hex</sub> = F031<sub>hex</sub> = 0000111100 0000110001<sub>bin</sub> =
> **110110**0000111100 **110111**0000110001<sub>bin</sub> = D83C DC31<sub>hex</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The following program will do the necessary work.  It may not be "manual" enough for your purposes, but at a minimum you can check your work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use utf8;
use autodie;
use warnings;
use warnings    qw< FATAL utf8 >;
no warnings     qw< uninitialized >;
use open        qw< :std :utf8 >;
use charnames   qw< :full >;
use feature     qw< unicode_strings >;

use Encode              qw< encode decode >;
use Unicode::Normalize  qw< NFD NFC >;

my ($x) = "mЖ丽";

open(U8,">:encoding(utf8)","/tmp/utf8-out");
print U8 $x;
close(U8);
open(U16,">:encoding(utf16)","/tmp/utf16-out");
print U16 $x;
close(U16);
system("od -t x1 /tmp/utf8-out");
my $u8 = encode("utf-8",$x);
print "utf-8: 0x".unpack("H*",$u8)."\n";

system("od -t x1 /tmp/utf16-out");
my $u16 = encode("utf-16",$x);
print "utf-16: 0x".unpack("H*",$u16)."\n";
```

Comment: Clever; I hadn't heard Perl introduced `>:encoding()`-style support yet. Thanks!