# Convert Escaped unicode to unicode in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

SO,

A seemingly simple question has me stumped. I have two statements:

```
NSLog(@"%@", @"\U0001f1ee\U0001f1f9");

NSLog(@"%@", @"\\U0001f1ee\\U0001f1f9");
```

The first outputs the correct emoji (Flag). The second outputs an escaped string. What conversion do I need to do to the second string to make it output the flag as well?

In other words: I have strings of escaped Unicode that I want to print out as the proper Emoji. How would I go about doing that?

I tried converting to `NSUTF8StringEncoding` NSData and then back to NSString, I tried using `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`, no joy. I must be using them wrong...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please try  NSString *name2escaped = @"\U0001f1ee\U0001f1f9";
        NSString *name2 = [NSString
            stringWithCString:[name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
            encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"name2 = %@", name2);

Comment: That doesn't work. I did see that post already though. :(

Comment: please this try may be solve your problem  NSString *input = @"\U0001f1ee\U0001f1f9"";
NSString *convertedString = [input mutableCopy];

CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);

NSLog(@"convertedString: %@", convertedString);

Comment: Tried that already. Remember, I want to convert an escaped string - so the input needs to be ````@"\\U0001f1ee\\U0001f1f9"```` with \\ not \

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234

Comment: Tried that already as well :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111084/discussion-between-rajesh-and-kivak-wolf).

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Use -stringByRemovingPercentEncoding.

```
NSString * string = @"\\U0001f1ee\\U0001f1f9" ;
NSLog( @"%@", [string stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]);
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work for me. It prints ````\U0001f1ee\U0001f1f9````

Answer (score 0):

This took far longer than I thought it would.

My final approach converts the Unicode escape sequences to their UTF8-equivalent bytes, encodes those as percent-escaped sequences, and then uses `[NSString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]` to yield the actual Unicode char.

You have to perform the bit shifting manually to complete the conversion, but the rest is trivial after that. For reference, you can look at [this example gist](https://gist.github.com/stephancasas/5e3f17978bff5e8387adf0731c749b48), which converts using the decimal codepoint-equivalent for Unicode monospace characters after resolving that value from a given ASCII-equivalent character in a larger string. The logic is written in JXA-ObjectiveC, but carries over perfectly into Objective-C.

---

**Update**:

Here's what a native Objective-C implementation would look like:

```objectivec
NSString* escapedUnicharToString(NSString* escapedUnicharString) {
    const char * escapedUnicharCString = [escapedUnicharString UTF8String];

    /// Marshal the hex chars to byte values.
    char unicharBytes[8] = {'\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
    unicharBytes[0] = escapedUnicharCString[2];
    unicharBytes[1] = escapedUnicharCString[3];
    unicharBytes[2] = escapedUnicharCString[4];
    unicharBytes[3] = escapedUnicharCString[5];
    unicharBytes[4] = escapedUnicharCString[6];
    unicharBytes[5] = escapedUnicharCString[7];
    unicharBytes[6] = escapedUnicharCString[8];
    unicharBytes[7] = escapedUnicharCString[9];
    
    /// Convert the marshaled bytes to their unichar-equivalent
    /// (`unsigned long`) value.
    unsigned long unicharIndex = strtoul(unicharBytes, NULL, 16);
    
    /// Convert the `unsigned long` to a binary string.
    NSMutableString *unicharBinaryString = [NSMutableString new];
    while (unicharIndex > 0) {
        unsigned long remainder = unicharIndex % 2;
        [unicharBinaryString appendFormat:@"%lu", remainder];
        unicharIndex /= 2;
    }
    
    /// Use the conversion mask for the *last* series of unicode chars.
    ///
    /// **Note**
    /// This must change if you're converting in a different range of
    /// unicode characters.
    ///
    /// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240184/12770455 for a list of
    /// alternate conversion masks.
    ///
    NSString *conversionMask = @"11110xxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx";
    
    NSMutableString *utf8BinaryString = [NSMutableString new];
    unsigned long utf8Offset = 0;

    /// Use the conversion mask to drop bits from the unichar binary
    /// string — beginning at the rightmost position and moving
    /// leftwards.
    ///
    /// The unichar binary string is reversed, so we'll fill-in
    /// each char using index 0.
    for (unsigned long i = [conversionMask length]; i > 0; i--) {
        unichar bit = [conversionMask characterAtIndex: (i - 1)];
        
        /// Fill-in the "x" characters from the unichar binary string.
        if (bit == 'x') {
            /// Fill with "0" when no chars remain.
            if (utf8Offset == [unicharBinaryString length]) {
                [utf8BinaryString insertString:@"0" atIndex:0];
                continue;
            }
            /// Fill with the current unichar binary offset char.
            [utf8BinaryString insertString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",
                                            [unicharBinaryString characterAtIndex: utf8Offset]] atIndex:0];
            utf8Offset++;
            continue;
        }
        
        /// Fill with the conversion mask's char.
        [utf8BinaryString insertString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", bit] atIndex:0];
    }
    
    /// Convert the UTF8-equivalent binary into its decimal-equivalent value.
    int decimal = 0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [utf8BinaryString length]; i++) {
        unichar character = [utf8BinaryString characterAtIndex:i];
        int bit = character - '0';
        decimal = (decimal * 2) + bit;
    }
    
    /// Convert the UTF8-equivalent decimal to its hex-string equivalent.
    NSMutableString *percentEncoded = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%08X", decimal];
    
    /// Insert percent chars before each hex-represented byte.
    [percentEncoded insertString:@"%" atIndex:0];
    [percentEncoded insertString:@"%" atIndex:3];
    [percentEncoded insertString:@"%" atIndex:6];
    [percentEncoded insertString:@"%" atIndex:9];

    /// Decode the percent-encoded UTF8 char, and return to caller.
    return [percentEncoded stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        NSLog(@"%@", escapedUnicharToString(@"\\U0001D670"));
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```