# Saving a unicode character to a UTF-8 file in C?

Tags: c, windows, utf-8

I've got a character in my app

```
ウ
```

stored in my app in Unicode

```
a6 30
```

(That's listed as 30A6 in the Katakana Unicode PDF I found on the web) (I'll worry about endian issues later)

In a UTF-8 text file opened in a hex editor it's stored as the multi-byte sequence

```
E3 82 A6
```

(which corresponds to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=10240) UTF-8 encoding list I found)

Is there an API for converting unicode to UTF8?

I'm working on old Win32 / c code which does not compile with unicode support. I could hook into C++ for STL / Boost support if that helps?

Comment: "Is there an API" - what about [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)?

Comment: OK this one's been around before - currently having a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240055/manually-converting-unicode-codepoints-into-utf-8-and-utf-16)

Comment: @ Aconcagua - Looks like ICU doesn't support 32 bit builds, older compilers. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Since this is a Win32 application, you might as well use the Win32 API function WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: @ Harry Johnston - Yes! I think it's a matter of understanding what it is I'm trying to achieve - now I'm getting my head round code pages and UTF - this worked first time, thank you