# How can U+203C be represented in (226, 128, 188) in swift chapter Strings and Characters?

Tags: swift, encoding

When I read The Swift Programming Language Strings and Characters. I don't know how U+203C (means !!) can represented by (226, 128, 188) in utf-8.

How did it happen ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually converting unicode codepoints into UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240055/manually-converting-unicode-codepoints-into-utf-8-and-utf-16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you already know how UTF-8 reserves certain bits to indicate that the Unicode character occupies several bytes. (This [website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm) can help).

First, write `0x203C` in binary:

```
0x230C = 10000000111100
```

So this character takes 16 bits to represent. Due to the "header bits" in the UTF-8 encoding scheme, it would take 3 bytes to encode it:

```
0x230C =           10     000000     111100 

             1st byte   2nd byte   3rd byte
             --------   --------   --------
header       1110       10         10
actual data        10     000000     111100
-------------------------------------------
full byte    11100010   10000000   10111100
decimal           226        128        188
```