# Golang unicode charactor value

Tags: go, unicode

I run this code and get an output, but why  the bytes value is E4B8AD and the int value is 20013. Why column 2 is not equal to column 5 ?

package main

```
import(
    "fmt"
)

func main(){

    str2 := "中文"

    fmt.Println("index int(rune) rune char bytes")
    for index, rune := range str2{
        fmt.Printf("%-2d      %d       %U '%c' %X\n", index, rune, rune, rune, []byte(string(rune)))
    }
}
```

the output is :

```
index int(rune) rune char bytes
0      20013       U+4E2D '中' E4B8AD
1      25991       U+6587 '文' E69687
```

Comment: Your output seems not to be correct: https://play.golang.org/p/dA22IPOWiC7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Unicode code point for a character is not necessarily the same as the byte representation of that character in a given character encoding.

For the character `中`, the code point is `U+4E2D`, but the byte representations in various character encodings are:

- `E4B8AD` (UTF-8)
- `4E2D` (UTF-16)
- `00004E2D` (UTF-32)

There's a really good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240819/3558960) that explains how to convert between code points and byte representations. There's also the excellent [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky.