# PHP5 translate byte sequence into UTF-8 sequence

Tags: php, php-5.6

Is there any simple way in PHP 5 to convert from unicode code points such as

```
U+1F9DB, U+200D, U+2642, U+FE0F
```

to a byte sequence

```
  F0  9F  A7  9B,   E2  80  8D,   E2  99  82,   EF  B8  8F
\xf0\x9f\xa7\x9b  \xe2\x80\x8d  \xe2\x99\x82  \xef\xb8\x8f
```

There are [tables](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl), but I assume, there's an easier way?

Comment: "simple" refers to "not hack the full stack to implement the logic behind UTF-8", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240055/manually-converting-unicode-codepoints-into-utf-8-and-utf-16

Comment: You should be using PHP7 by now. PHP5 is end of life and has been for a good while.

Comment: I am, but not all of the people using my software ;)
But, yes, if there's no simple solution, I shall make a few people angry.

Comment: Choose between making them angry or by using insecure and unmaintained software. PHP has a host of security and efficiency issues that have been fixed over the last 15 years; and now PHP5 is no longer maintained, certain hackers will be specifically working on breaching PHP5 because of things like your business who have it and have not yet updated it. [read more](https://dev.to/david_j_eddy/php-5-end-of-life-is-upon-us-why-you-should-care-3gpk)