# Decoding a file that is encoded using CP437 table

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decode, encode

I have to write a program to decode a file (which is encoded using CP437) by replacing each symbol's Unicode according to the CP437 table, then converting it to UTF-8 and printing the output to a file.

I have two files - an input file which contains a long text with both normal characters and some weird characters (in the result file those weird characters will be replaced by various dashes), and a CP437 file which contains 256 lines of pairs (the first part is a decimal number, the second one is Unicode, for example, 73 0049).

This is how I'm trying to solve this problem:

1. Open the input file using the 'RB' flag
2. Since I'm opening the file using 'RB', I read every symbol as bytes and then store it in the 'text' list
3. After I'm done reading the file, I loop through the text list
4. During the loop, I get the decimal value of the symbol
5. I get the Unicode from the CP437.txt file using the decimal value
6. I convert the Unicode to 0s and 1s
7. I convert the binary representation of the Unicode to UTF-8 and
   receive 0s and 1s back
8. I convert those UTF-8 0s and 1s to bytes and write them to the
   results file that is opened with the 'WB' flag

Also, if the length of the UTF-8 0s and 1s is longer than 8, then I split it every 8 characters and then convert those into bytes (I'm not sure if this is correct)

The main problem is that when I try to write the results, I get a lot of gibberish characters and I'm not sure where is the problem. ANY help is appreciated, I've been stuck with this assignment for a while now and just can't figure out what's the problem.

```
def convertBinToHex(binary):
    binToHex = hex(int(binary, 2))
    temp = list(binToHex)
    temp = temp[2:]
    binToHex = "".join(temp).upper()
    return binToHex


def convertUnicodeToUTF(unicodeBin, symbolDecimal, returnBin):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240055/manually-converting-unicode-codepoints-into-utf-8-and-utf-16
    bytesCount = 0
    if int("0000", 16) <= symbolDecimal <= int("007F", 16):
        if returnBin:
            return unicodeBin
        return convertBinToHex(unicodeBin)
    elif int("0080", 16) <= symbolDecimal <= int("07FF", 16):
        bytesCount = 2
    elif int("0800", 16) <= symbolDecimal <= int("FFFF", 16):
        bytesCount = 3
    elif int("10000", 16) <= symbolDecimal <= int("10FFFF", 16):
        bytesCount = 4
    else:
        return

    if bytesCount == 2:
        template = ['1', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
    elif bytesCount == 3:
        template = ['1', '1', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '0', 'x', 'x',
                    'x',
                    'x', 'x', 'x']
    elif bytesCount == 4:
        template = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '0', 'x', 'x',
                    'x',
                    'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '0', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
    else:
        return

    results = []
    unicodeList = list(unicodeBin)
    counter = len(unicodeList) - 1

    for el in reversed(template):
        if el == 'x':
            if counter >= 0:
                results.append(unicodeList[counter])
                counter -= 1
            else:
                results.append('0')
        elif el == '0':
            results.append('0')
        else:
            results.append('1')

    results.reverse()
    results = "".join(results)

    if returnBin:
        return results
    else:
        return convertBinToHex(results)



codePage = {}
with open("CP437.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        codePage[key] = val

text = []

with open("386intel.txt", 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if c:
            # Converts bytes to bits (string)
            text.append("{:08b}".format(int(c.hex(), 16)))
        if not c:
            print("End of file")
            break


bytesString = 0
bytesStringInt = 0
resultFile = open("rez.txt", "wb")

for item in text:
    decimalValue = int(item, 2)
    newUnicode = codePage[str(decimalValue)]
    unicodeToBin = "{0:08b}".format(int(newUnicode, 16))
    bytesString = convertUnicodeToUTF(unicodeToBin, decimalValue, True)
    if len(bytesString) > 8:
        bytesStringSplit = [bytesString[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(bytesString), 8)]
        for x in bytesStringSplit:
            bytesStringInt = int(x, 2)
            resultFile.write(bytes([bytesStringInt]))
            # print(bytes([bytesStringInt]))
    else:
        bytesStringInt = int(bytesString, 2)
        resultFile.write(bytes([bytesStringInt]))
        # print(bytes([bytesStringInt]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested because you neglected to provide the input files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @cp;
{
    open my $fh, '<', 'CP437.txt';
    while (my $line = readline $fh) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($k, $v) = split ' ', $line;
        $cp[$k] = chr hex $v;
    }
}
{
    open my $in, '<:raw', '386intel.txt';
    open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', '386intel.txt.utf8';
    while (my $line = readline $in) {
        $out->print(
            join '',            # 5. join characters into string
            map {               # 2. loop over octets
                $cp[            # 4. look up character corresponding to
                                    # octet numeric value
                    ord         # 3. numeric value of octet
                ]
            }
            split '', $line     # 1. split line into octets
        );
    }
}
```

The program is quite easy to understand with only 10 lines of significant code (and also easy to port to Python, if needed).

---

If the file CP437.txt follows the standard, then it simply becomes:

```
› piconv -f CP437 -t UTF-8 < 386intel.txt > 386intel.txt.utf8
```

---

In case the assignment really involves manual encoding to UTF-8 instead of using a library, then substitute at the place in the code where the `chr` function is.