# why utf-8 encoding does not use 4 hexadecimal digits. It maps 4 hexadecimal digits code points to pair of 2 hexadecimal digits

Tags: encoding, utf-8, hex

I have a unicode character `Ņ` whose HEX is `U+0145` and integer is `325`

When encoded using `UTF-8` into bytes its not represented as `\x145 [= 325 base10]` but represented as `\xc5\x85` i.e in unicode `\xc5 [197 base10] - Å and \x85 [133 base10]   (i.e = 197 + 133 = 330 != 325)`

Why is it so.

One advantage is that by using 2 digit hexadecimals it will use 1 byte (2 hexadecimal digits use 4 x 2 = 8 bits)

Comment: You are completely mixing up technical terms. The encoding doesn’t use hexadecimal digits. You are using them. Perhaps, you are looking at the result using a tool which displays the result in hexadecimal form. The encoded form consists of just two bytes, regardless of how you display them. And one byte can only encode 256 different values, hence, you can not encode the number 325 in one byte. It’s not clear why you think summing up the two bytes of the encoded form produces something meaningful.

Comment: Your Unicode character has the code point `U+0145`, and there is a non-obvious algorithm for converting that code point into the UTF-8 bytes `0xC5 0x85`. I have linked to the question [Manually converting unicode codepoints into UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6240055/2985643) for which the accepted answer explains in full detail how that is done. I'm therefore voting to close your question as a duplicate of that one, but please push back if that doesn't help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually converting unicode codepoints into UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240055/manually-converting-unicode-codepoints-into-utf-8-and-utf-16)