# How to write Unicode symbol manually into array C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

Why this code doesn't print `А`?

```
int main() {
    char str[] = {0x0, 0x4, 0x1, 0x0};
    write(1, str, 4);
}
```

Instead of `A` it just print nothing and exit. This is strange because hexadecimal value of `A` is [U+0410](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0410).

Comment: `A` would just be `0x41`. And chars are represented by 2 hexadecimal characters, not 1. 1 hexadecimal character is a nibble, 2 make a byte.

Comment: This question is tagged UTF8, but that is not the correct way to encode U+0410 as UTF8. That would be encoded as 0xD0 0x90. See also: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240184/14926026, you will see that the cyrillic A is not `{0x0, 0x4, 0x1, 0x0}`, but actually `{ 0xd0, 0x90 }`

```
int main()
{
   char str[] = { 0xd0, 0x90 };
   write(1, str, 2);
}
```

Comment: Use this tool to convert unicode to UTF-8 https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

Answer (score 1):

Your post contains both

U+000041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A (A)

and

U+000410 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A (А)

Either way, you need to encode the character using the encoding expected by the terminal. Assuming a terminal expecting UTF-8,

```
$ perl -e'use utf8; $_ = "A";         utf8::encode($_); printf "%v02X", $_;'
41

$ perl -e'use utf8; $_ = "\N{U+41}";  utf8::encode($_); printf "%v02X", $_;'
41

$ perl -e'use utf8; $_ = chr(0x41)";  utf8::encode($_); printf "%v02X", $_;'
41

$ perl -e'use utf8; $_ = "А";         utf8::encode($_); printf "%v02X", $_;'
D0.90

$ perl -e'use utf8; $_ = "\N{U+410}"; utf8::encode($_); printf "%v02X", $_;'
D0.90

$ perl -e'use utf8; $_ = chr(0x410);  utf8::encode($_); printf "%v02X", $_;'
D0.90
```

So you want

```c
const char *str = "\x41";      // { 0x41, 0 }
printf("%s\n", str);           // write(1, str, 1);
```

or

```c
const char *str = "\xD0\x90";  // { 0xD0, 0x90, 0 }
printf("%s\n", str);           // write(1, str, 2);
```

(No point in using `write`, but you could.)